# How to get value from SRC and then Display in another Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below HTML is generated by a bunch of JS that i cannot change.

```
<div class="classname1">
    <video disableremoteplayback="" preload="none" playsinline="" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <source
            type="video/mp4"
            src="https://simple.url.link"
        />
    </video>
    <div class="classname2"><canvas width="964" height="542"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

Below HTML is already in the document somewhere

```
<div id="bhadoo-dl" class="classname3">
</div>
```

Work needs to be done: I want to get `https://simple.url.link` which is dynamic from src

and then display it in div with `id="bhadoo-dl"` with content `<a href="">DL</a>` tag using JS. (i know how to print this in div. i am unable to fetch the src data.

working on this site. (18+ content, proceed with caution, URL is temporary)
`https://exss.pornproxy.workers.dev/view_video.php?viewkey=ph5f36910706a6a`

```
<div class="mhp1138_videoWrapper"><video disableremoteplayback="" preload="none" playsinline="" style="visibility: hidden;"><source type="video/mp4" src="videourl"></video><div class="mhp1138_screenshot"><canvas width="660" height="371"></canvas></div></div>
```

```
<a id="bhadoo-dl" href="">Download</a>
```

loading the js code from
`https://workspace.parveenbhadoo.com/s.js`

`https://imgur.com/C6yDwUl`
`https://imgur.com/Sedu22f`

I've tried several things.

Comment: `$(".classname1 > video > source").attr("src")` seems to work ok https://jsfiddle.net/wrxh42ta/ - what *did* you try?

Comment: what have you tried? We expect that you'll do some research and make an attempt before posting a question here.

Comment: is it inside an <iframe> ?

Comment: updated post with more data.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
const src = $(".classname1 > video").find('source').attr("src")
$('#bhadoo-dl').attr('href',src)
```

Comment: it will work directly, but not in this case. check the updated post.

Comment: please clarify your updated post, i dont understand, or you can explain it here

Comment: view source of given site. and the button Download. I am fetching it from the src and displaying the link on download button from video url.